# How to run a Data Looker Report with dynamic bigquery table names as data sources?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker, looker-studio

I have a data looker report that runs on a specific table schema. However those tables are generated automatically and I want to run the same report over different tables that are generated automatically. (over 1000)

How can I achieve that? Tried with dynamic SQL and it doesn't work (see below).
Did anyone happened to solve such a solution?

Seems that bigquery custom SQL doesn't allow to use params in as table names:

This one won't work:

```
DECLARE tablename STRING;
SET tablename = "100_dwd_rfm_analysis_ms";

select * from tablename
```

Neither passing the whole SQL as a custom query:

```
@custom_query
```

And this one doesn't either:

```
select * from database.@table_name
```